# Re-Associating an ImageList with it's Keys

Tags: c#, serialization, icons, client-server

I have a Client and a Server. The Server retrieves a list of applications (Each containing a Path, Name and Icon) from it's desktop. It then sends the Application back to the Client, to be displayed in a ListView with LargeIcons so that the client can then double click on the desktop icons in the listview and have that application open on the server. (This works 100% when being done with the below bug...)

However, there is a Microsoft bug in which a serialized Icon will be degraded when deserialized (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814735)

I'm trying to follow the advice given there in order to bring back over high quality icons.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
//Get the list of Applications, which will include an icon, which we'll ignore due to the bug.
List<App> apps = client.ServiceProxy.getDesktopShortcuts();
// Get the ImageListStreamer (The serializable portion of the ImageList) and assign it to our Image List
ImageListStreamer il = client.ServiceProxy.getDesktopIcons();

foreach (App app in apps){
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(app.name);
    item.ImageKey = app.path;
    lv.Items.Add(item);
}
```

When I add the icons to the ImageList in getDesktopIcons(), I do it as follows:

```
il.Images.Add(app.path, app.icon);
```

So as to have the Applications' path be it's key. However, I believe when I send just the image stream back to the client, it loses that key information. I have the app's path in each App object, so how can I associate them back, in order, with their respective icon in the imagelist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple. Since both my List and ImageList are being constructed in the same order, it's safe to assume when I loop through the apps I've been given, then Apps[0] will correspond to ImageList[0].

Therefore, I need simply to use

```
il.Images.SetKeyName(i, app.path);
```

with the index of the image to set (Corresponding to the application).